# is there a way to get the file names which need to be updated if TFS status.Numoperations != 0?

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

I have a piece of code which looks at the status of a workspace, something like below.

```
var status = workspace.Get(request, GetOptions.Preview).NumOperations;
```

if status is greater than zero I want to know the names of or the complete path of files on which the get operation will be performed. i plan on doing a selective get after getting the list of files.

is this possible?

Comment: Did you refer to the documentation? What problems are you having implementing your solution?

Comment: I'm looking into the documentation and still haven't found anything useful yet, maybe I'm looking wrong. It's just that I want to do a selective get latest on my directory after taking a look at what file needs to be updated.

Comment: @AhmedDaniel Have you checked the [VersionControlServer.GetItems Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.getitems(v=vs.120).aspx), if not, you can check if that helps. Also this link: https://paulselles.wordpress.com/2014/01/08/team-foundation-server-api-programmatically-downloading-files-from-source-control/

Comment: No both links don't seem to have what I need. the GetItems method downloads the items or gets a complete list of all the items in the specified path. Let me elaborate a bit more. I have a situation where for some network reason some files don't get downloaded, so the next time I do a get request again. At this stage I have figured out that some of the larger files cause this issue. So, I wanted to avoid this by not downloading these larger files and I thought if i get a list of items which are left to be downloaded I can avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to query the changesets between your local workspace and server and then parse the changed files in the changeset.

Use `VersionControlServer.QueryHistory()` to get the chanages:

```
var changes = vcs.QueryHistory("$/ServerPath", VersionSpec.Latest, 0, RecursionType.Full, null, new WorkspaceVersionSpec(localworkspace),null,Int32.MaxValue,true,true);
```

Comment: Thanks this helped... I was looking at the issue in the wrong way :(,  by getting the changed files between local and server I was able to do what I wanted.